# I need to open web page using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

I need to open a website, log in to it, and after it displays opened webpage (some DIVs) in my Flask web server.

Website is  https://home.solarman.cn/login.html

I tried this code for login

```
import requests

POSTLOGINURL = 'https://home.solarman.cn/login.html'

REQUESTURL = 'https://home.solarman.cn/main.html'


payload = {
    'username': '',
    'pass': ''
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POSTLOGINURL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUESTURL)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: ...and? What happened? How does this relate to Flask?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's why the `down-vote` invented

Comment: This code does not relate to Flask. This code just for login

Comment: @SahakSahakyan you have still not mentioned what is the problem here?

Comment: In this code no problem, me need another code to login website and display it in Flask web server

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

target = "https://home.solarman.cn/main.html"

data = {
    "userName": "user@user.com",
    "userNameDisplay": "user@user.com",
    "password": "yourpass",
    "lan": "2",
    "domain": "home.solarman.cn",
    "userType": "C"
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(url, data=data).json()
        print(r)
        r = req.get(target)
        print(r)


main("https://home.solarman.cn/cpro/login/validateLogin.json")
```

Comment: Me need to display the webpage in Flask web server for example using <iframe>

Comment: I see english is the main problem of this question